# Jquery show alert after click submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Let's say I have a form like following:

```
<form name="add" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD">
</form>
```

My question is how do I show the "Form submitted" after I click ADD button using jQuery? 
Here is what I have tried (I'm using Jquery 1.11.1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").submit(function(){
        alert("Form submitted");
    });
});
</script>
```

Am I write correct? Or any other ways to write it?

Comment: Why are you using the same name for form name and submit button? First change that.... and then change `submit` to `click` in jQuery code....

Comment: yes change submit as click.. function and form name you need to use different from input name need not be same no problem with jquery versions for this ..

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="add" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD">
</form>
```

your input type is submit it will automatically submit the form you can change this type to `button`

```
<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="ADD">
```

and change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").submit(function(){
        alert("Form submitted");
    });
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Form submitted");
    });
});
```

[event.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Comment: @KKLMichael glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(e){
        alert("Form submitted");
        return false;

    });
});
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/dn28Lze1/1/

Answer (score 0):

assign a click   handler to the button

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
            alert("Form submitted");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Form submitted");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#add` id should attach on `form`, not the `submit button`. See below :

Remove id from input :

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="ADD">
```

And add to form :

```
<form name="add" id="add" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And of course with the current script you had, after click ok button it will redirect into form action, just in case you wanna stay on that page without reloading, you must prevent the behavior of form from being like a normal form does by `returning false` or use jquery `.preventDefault()` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Form submitted");
    // or return false;
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ecne0hmq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#add").on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $(".add");
       form.submit();
       alert("Form submitted");
    });
});
</script>
```

When you have the form in a variable we can perform other queries as well, such as we can use `if` condition or we can serialize the form `var form = $(".add").serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is add an onclick method to your form to initiate the javascript containing the alert.

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
function showMessage() {
alert ("Form submitted");
return true;
}
</script>
<form name="add" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick = "return showMessage()" />
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD"> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's just add an id attribute for your form and use the id for the submit event, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<form id="frm_add" name="add" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm_add").submit(function(){
        alert("Form submitted");

    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form using ajax and then you want to show the alert message that "form is submitted successfully"

then you can use this code

// this is the id of the form

$("#add").submit(function(e) {

```
var url = "add.php"; // Your PHP page.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#add").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
```

});

you can also use JSON it depends on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The`onsubmit` event occurs when a form is submitted.

`onSubmit`is a scripting event that occurs when the user attempts to submit the form to the CGI. onSubmit can be used to do some error checking on the form data, and to cancel the submit if an error is found.

Note that in order to cancel the submit event, the onSubmit should be in the form `onSubmit="return expression"`. `return` indicates that the value of the expression should be returned to the submit routine. If the expression evaluates to false, the submit routine is cancelled; if it is true, the submit routine goes forward.

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
}
</script>
```

[Working Example For Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit)